# Cannot find a executable file after I move it to another folder in $PATH

Tags: linux, environment-variables

A little experiment on linux.

```
root@ubuntu:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
root@ubuntu:/# which ls
/bin/ls
root@ubuntu:/# mv /bin/ls /root
root@ubuntu:/# ls
bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/# export PATH=$PATH:/root
root@ubuntu:/# ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home ...
root@ubuntu:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/root
root@ubuntu:/# mv /root/ls /bin/
root@ubuntu:/# ls
bash: /root/ls: No such file or directory
```

I just moved /bin/ls to /root, then I add /root to $PATH, now ls is executable.

When I move /root/ls to /bin/ again, 'ls' is not able to execute, the system just can't find the file 'ls'. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete bash's cached path for the executable.

```
hash -d ls
```

Comment: Is it able to disable bash's cache ?